# question of basic understanding: objects scope

Tags: javascript, scope

when i instance an object ([simplegallery](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex4/simplegallery.js)) in a normal function like this:

```
function setGallery(imgs){
    var galleryArray = new Array();
    for(var i=0; i<imgs.length; i++){
        galleryArray.push([imgs[i].imgpath + imgs[i].imghash + imgs[i].thumb + '.' + imgs[i].ext, "", "", ""]);
    }

    var mygallery=new simpleGallery({
        navpanelheight: 40,
        wrapperid: "fbImg", //ID of main gallery container,
        dimensions: [80, 60], //width/height of gallery in pixels. Should reflect dimensions of the images exactly
        imagearray: galleryArray,
        autoplay: [false, 2500, 2], //[auto_play_boolean, delay_btw_slide_millisec, cycles_before_stopping_int]
        persist: false, //remember last viewed slide and recall within same session?
        fadeduration: 500, //transition duration (milliseconds)
        oninit:function(){ //event that fires when gallery has initialized/ ready to run
            //Keyword "this": references current gallery instance (ie: try this.navigate("play/pause"))
        },
        onslide:function(curslide, i){ //event that fires after each slide is shown
            //Keyword "this": references current gallery instance
            //curslide: returns DOM reference to current slide's DIV (ie: try alert(curslide.innerHTML)
            //i: integer reflecting current image within collection being shown (0=1st image, 1=2nd etc)
        }
    });
}
```

From my understandig, the created object "mygallery" is an instance of "simpleGallery". Because the object "mygallery" is declared in the function setGallery it is a local object which will be lost after the function is finished. But simpleGallery binds events, that interact with settings, which are properties of simpleGallery ... how comes those properties are still alive when thos events are triggered?

However, how long does such an instance live and why?

1. Qestion: How can i access a property of this instance from an other function than setGallery?
   Like when i want to get the value of mygallery.setting.imagearray.length ...

Thanks for your helping me understand! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript has function scope, all variables inside a function
(declared with var) are only visible in and anywhere in that
function.

A function **is an object** and the lifetime of that object does
not necessarily end when you leave the function body. For example
`setGallery` will 'live' because `mygallery` continues to 'live', but
access to `mygallery` is lost (i'm sure there will be a lot of
suggestions of solutions in other posts).

Comment: In other words: only **variables** (i.e. the "names") care about scope. **Objects** can live across scope-boundaries.

Answer (score 3):

In this case local variable is not destroyed after function ends because simpleGallery sets bind events on DOM I suppose. You see If javascript sees that some objects are referenced by something outside it holds those in memory.
This object will live in memory up to the finish of program or all references will be cleared.
To get `imagearray.length` you need some event to be fired in scope of the object. To achieve this you need to change `simpleGallery` class to set up event and the callback function to be fired in scope of `this`
If you add example below to `simpleGallery` constructor than `onclick` event on `domElement` will fire a function `someYourFunction` within scope of `simpleGallery` instance. So in this function you will have access to `this.imagearray.length`

```
var self=this;
domElement.addEventListener(
  "click",
  function(event) {someYourFunction.apply(self, event)},
  false);
```

Comment: I think this is correct, yet not concise. Except for the DOM part -- the rule is "what is pointed to is not garbage collected", no matter if the reference is a DOM reference or not.

Comment: Yes I agree with you. I meant this exact case.

Answer (score 1):

setting  is the public membe of simpleGallery so you can access the setting on its object. Now you need to manage simpleGallery object(myGallary) to access setting, possible ways for this can be one of following:

1) Return mygallery object from setGallery then you can call it in following way

```
  setGallery(img).setting.imagearray.length.. or 
 var gallary = setGallery(img);
 gallary.setting.imagearray.length....
```

2) Make setGallary a class like simpleGallery and define myGallary as public member using this

```
  var setGallery = function(img){
   ................
    this.myGallary = new simpleGallery( ..
   .. .. 

   }

   then access it as 
   var gallary = new setGallary(img);
   gallary.myGallary.setting.imagearray.length
```

3) the dirty way, create an global variable to hold the myGallary object and assign it in the setGallary function and use it anywhere.